# This form should not contain extra fields. on multile submite button

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a two part form in symfony2 of a single table db.
On my edit page i display whole form with two save buttons.
when i edit some field and try to save it that shows the extra field error
my controller code is

```
  $form = $this->createForm(new PatientfullType(), $test, array());
    $formadd = $this->createForm(new PatientfulladdType(), $test, array());
.
.
if ($form->get('save')->isClicked()) {

return $this->render('AdminBundle:FormsController:patientformfull.html.twig', array('formadd' => $formadd->createView(),'form' => $form->createView() ));
    // probably redirect to the add page again
}

else
    {   


        return $this->render('AdminBundle:FormsController:patientformfull.html.twig', array('formadd' => $formadd->createView(),'form' => $form->createView() ));
    }
```

my twig file has two object

form and formadd

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            {{ form_label(form.sex) }} 
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            {{ form_widget(form.sex, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }} 
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            {{ form_label(formadd.ChronicDiseases) }} 
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            {{ form_widget(formadd.ChronicDiseases, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }} 
        </div>
    </div>
 </div><div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-5">
            {{ form_widget(form.save , {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-success'}}) }}

            {{ form_widget(form.cancel , {'attr': {'onclick': 'cancelRedirect()','class': 'btn btn-default'}}) }}

        </div> 


         </div><div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-5">
            {{ form_widget(formadd.save1 , {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-success'}}) }}


        </div>
```

Comment: I can't understand what is the question.

Comment: how to handle two form types on single view with two submit button